# Google DoubleClick close button doubling up

Tags: double-click, double-click-advertising

When testing an ad locally I only have one close button, but when testing in DoubleClick Studio a second button and white bottom and left borders are added.

Can someone explain how I obtain a result with only one close button?

[image: Ad image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are uploading to Studio with a wrong dimension..